# How to configure Apache Tomcat on a Windows 8.1 installation?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, environment-variables

I'm trying to install a 64bit Apache Tomcat distribution on a Windows 8.1 machine but the way in which I have set the environment variables seems to be incorrect.

The steps I have gone through in setting up are as follows:

1. Copy/Paste `apache-tomcat-7.0.57` folder into `Program Files (x86)`
2. Set environment variables in the environment variables gui.
3. Set TOMCAT_HOME to the location of the Tomcat folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.57`
4. Set CATALINA_HOME to the location of the Tomcat folder also: `C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.57`

But when I execute `%TOMCAT_HOME%\bin\startup` to check it has been installed correctly I get the following error in my CMD:

`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I found a related question on SO and it gave me the following fix but that http://goo.gl/aNmxGM but that threw another error below:

`files was unexpected at this time`

I gathered from this that there is a problem in the way I'm setting up the environment variables or possibly the placement of the Tomcat folder. Does anyone have any advice on a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you really need is to put it between "" as your path contains space

```
"%TOMCAT_HOME%\bin\startup"
```

or

```
"%TOMCAT_HOME%"\bin\startup
```

I hope this could help!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
"%CATALINA_HOME%"\bin\startup
```

in the command prompt if you have set the environment variables correctly. I have tried it and it has worked well.